# parsing responseXML in Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, xml

I'm trying to debug a web application that uses Ajax to send an SQL query and parse the results as XML, and I'm running into multiple problems.  First, responseXML is coming back as null, even though responseText looks like valid XML.

This is the PHP code that creates my XML response:

```
$d = new DomDocument('1.0');
$d->formatOutput = true;

$res = $d->appendChild($d->createElement('response'));

foreach($results as $id => $options) {
    $sel = $res->appendChild($d->createElement('select'));
    $sel->setAttribute('id', $id);

    foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
       $op = $sel->appendChild($d->createElement('option',htmlentities($option)));
       $op->setAttribute('value', $value);
  }
}
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $d->saveXML($d)."\n";
```

and this is what comes back in responseText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<select id="CruiseSelect">
<option value=" ">All Cruises</option>
<option value="0507NH">0507NH</option>
<option value="0511NH">0511NH</option>
<option value="0602JD">0602JD</option>
<option value="0604NH">0604NH</option>
<option value="0607NH">0607NH</option>
</select>
</response>
```

I couldn't find a way to fix responseXML, but I thought I found a workaround like this:

```
var xmldoc;
    try{
       xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(test, "text/xml");
    } catch (e){
            alert('XML parsing error');
    }
    var selects = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('select');
```

This seemed to work at first, but when I tried to keep going, I discovered that the length of selects is 0, and I couldn't get the options values out of it.  Am I missing something really obvious here?  What's wrong with my XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer and wow, it was really annoying.

I realized that my echo->$d->saveXML($d) command was sticking an extraneous line break at the very beginning of the XML string it was returning to Ajax.  A little further research revealed that other people have had a similar issue.  Following their suggestions, I went through every php file in my code and removed any blank lines or spaces at the end of the files.  This fixed the problem.